# Could not load file or assembly Newtonsoft.Json . Issue with version

Tags: c#

I am currently having issue with referencing Newtonsoft.Json in my .net 4.8 application. I have been checking all that is on the internet but not got a solution yet. I have been getting the following error.

```
System.IO.FileLoadException
  HResult=0x80131040
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.3.27908, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
  Source=TRFBusServiceProxies
  StackTrace:
   at TRFBusServiceProxies.CRD.LMECRDAPIClient.<GetAllMembers>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at TRFBusServiceProxies.CRD.LMECRDAPIClient.GetAllMembers()
   at TRFBusServiceAgents.LMECRDClient.<GetAllMembers>d__7.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at TRFBusServiceAgents.Tests.BusServiceAgentModuleTests.<CRDRetrieval_GetAllMembers>d__16.MoveNext() in C:\Development\trfbusserviceagents\TRFBusServiceAgentsSolution\TRFBusServiceAgents.Tests\BusServiceAgentModule.Tests.cs:line 285

Inner Exception 1:
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I have tried couple of version combination in the app.config but nothing has helped so far. When I right click the properties of the dll , I can see the file version as 13.0.3.27908. I am not sure if the app.config is correct.

Comment: Delete the reference, clean solution, close Visual Studio. All instances if more than one is running. Reopen, add the nuget, try build. What happens?

Comment: Do you have more than one project in the solution? If so, you may also want to check out the "consolidate" tab in the solution nuget manager. It will tell you if different projects reference different versions of a nuget. I always try and keep all versions in a solution the same.

Comment: I have four projects in the solution and there are only two of them that use newtonsoft and both are the same versions. The only difference between the two projects is the binding in the app.config.  The other project <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.3.27908" newVersion="13.0.3.27908"/>   . I dont have a consolidate tab. Also I have tried to close all other visual studio intsances and rebuild it. No luck so far

Comment: Do you think the bindingdirect differences in both the project make a difference

Comment: Consolidate tab shows up when you manage packages for the solution.

Comment: Thanks .I checked the consolidate tab and newton soft doesn't show up so I believe its not an issue with different versions